# How to use my own tagged file. txt as corpus in NLTK ? (python 2.7)

Tags: python

I find this code but when I tried to use it I got the following Error :

```
        import nltk
        from nltk.corpus import PlaintextCorpusReader
        corpus_root = 'C:\Users\User\Desktop' 
        wordlists = PlaintextCorpusReader(corpus_root, 'rxml.txt') 
        wordlists.fileids()
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree

Answer (score -1):

```
ImportError: No module named etree.ElementTree
```

This error means that you have not import the module `etree.ElementTree`

In order to resolve this, just import the module

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
```

Resources : https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html